# Android PUT and POST request transform to GET

Tags: android, android-volley, retrofit

I have tested Volley and Retrofit libs for GET and POST requests to my server. Server shows them as GET requests. iOS AFNetworking requests for same api works correct. Why it can be?

PS.
I use this code for Volley, in all examples in inet there are only needed POST method and 'getParams'. getParams is not called in my case

```java
public void createSession(final String guid,
                          final String name,
                          final String comment,
                          final Date startDate,
                          final Date endDate,
                          final BooleanCallback callback) {

    JsonObjectRequest registerRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, ServerAPIBaseURLString + "sessions/",
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
            return headers();
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("uuid", guid);
            params.put("name", name);
            params.put("comment", comment);
            params.put("start_date", timestampRepresentation(startDate));
            params.put("end_date", timestampRepresentation(endDate));

            return params;
        }

    };

    queue.add(registerRequest);
}
```

I have found that iOS log on server is (401 is not matter)

"PUT /api/sessions/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
"PUT /ru/api/sessions/ HTTP/1.1" 401 210

but Android

"POST /api/sessions/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
"GET /ru/api/sessions/ HTTP/1.1" 405 114

Answer (score 0):

Can you break your code into parts and see if it works.

It will be something like this:

Your listener on success:

```
Response.Listener<String> listener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {


            }
        };
```

Your listener on error:

```
Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


            }


        };
```

Actual post request with params:

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest( Request.Method.POST, url, listener, errorListener){

            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                params.put("uuid", uuid);

                return  params;
            };

        };
```

Calling the request:

```
queue.add(request);
```

Comment: I have tried exactly your code and it give GET on server

Comment: I use server on my computer and clients on phones. So I think iOS and Android on an equal footing

Comment: Can you also add your server's log that shows you received GET?

Comment: [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxgoNibWI-l4TDNjd1NySHJyYVk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Also I have added extra to main topic